# Compare two Lists element-wise containing reference types

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to compare two lists containing reference types (custom classes) element-wise, ignoring order. My question relates to the `Equals` method as shown below.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Luxaudi.ViewModels
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Contains information from the Canvas class that is relevant to the user interface.
    /// </summary>
    internal sealed class CanvasViewModel : ViewModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The display title of the canvas.
        /// </summary>
        public readonly string Title;
        /// <summary>
        /// The timeline view model belonging to the canvas view model.
        /// </summary>
        public readonly TimelineViewModel TimelineViewModel;
        /// <summary>
        /// Contains information from the Canvas class that is relevant to the user interface.
        /// </summary>
        public readonly List<NoteMapViewModel> NoteMapViewModels;
        /// <summary>
        /// Contains information from the Canvas class that is relevant to the user interface.
        /// </summary>
        public readonly List<ScaleViewModel> ScaleViewModels;

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="title">The display title of the canvas project.</param>
        /// <param name="timelineViewModel">The timeline view model which represents the Timeline of the Canvas.</param>
        public CanvasViewModel(string title, TimelineViewModel timelineViewModel)
        {
            Title = title;
            TimelineViewModel = timelineViewModel;
            ScaleViewModels = new List<ScaleViewModel>();
            NoteMapViewModels = new List<NoteMapViewModel>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="title">The display title of the canvas project.</param>
        /// <param name="timelineViewModel">The timeline view model which represents the Timeline of the Canvas.</param>
        /// <param name="scaleViewModels">The collection of scale view models belonging to the canvas view model.</param>
        /// <param name="noteMapViewModels">The collection of note map view models belonging to the canvas view model.</param>
        public CanvasViewModel(string title, TimelineViewModel timelineViewModel, List<ScaleViewModel> scaleViewModels, 
                               List<NoteMapViewModel> noteMapViewModels)
        {
            Title = title;
            TimelineViewModel = timelineViewModel;
            ScaleViewModels = scaleViewModels;
            NoteMapViewModels = noteMapViewModels;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Compare two CanvasViewModels for object equality.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj">The object to check for equality with.</param>
        /// <returns>False if the object is not a CanvasViewModel or the member attributes are not equal.</returns>
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            CanvasViewModel canvasViewModel = obj as CanvasViewModel;
            if(canvasViewModel != null)
            {
                if (canvasViewModel.Title == Title && canvasViewModel.TimelineViewModel == TimelineViewModel &&
                    canvasViewModel.ScaleViewModels.All(ScaleViewModels.Contains) && 
                    canvasViewModel.ScaleViewModels.Count == ScaleViewModels.Count &&
                    canvasViewModel.NoteMapViewModels.All(NoteMapViewModels.Contains) &&
                    canvasViewModel.NoteMapViewModels.Count == NoteMapViewModels.Count)
                    return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The CanvasViewModel inherits from the generic ViewModel class:

```
namespace Luxaudi.ViewModels
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The basic template of all view models. Contains information from domain classes that is relevant to the user interface.
    /// </summary>
    internal abstract class ViewModel
    {
        public override abstract bool Equals(object obj);
    }
}
```

Any gotchas to look out for here?

EDIT: Full code provided as recommended.

Answer (score 3):

It looks OK to me, but you could optimize a little bit by comparing the "low-hanging fruits" first:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
  CanvasViewModel other = obj as CanvasViewModel;

  return ReferenceEquals(this, other) // other == this is "unsafe" if == is implemented by calling Equals().
    || other != null
    && other.ScaleViewModels.Count == ScaleViewModels.Count
    && other.NoteMapViewModels.Count == NoteMapViewModels.Count
    && other.Title == Title
    && other.TimelineViewModel == TimelineViewModel
    && other.ScaleViewModels.All(ScaleViewModels.Contains)
    && other.NoteMapViewModels.All(NoteMapViewModels.Contains);
}
```

Here it is first checked if the argument (reference) equals `this`. If it does, no further comparison is necessary. Further the scalars `ScaleViewModels.Count` and `NoteMapViewModels.Count` are fairly cheap to compare - compared to `other.ScaleViewModels.All(...)` and if they are different there is no need for further comparison etc...

Comment: Would adding parentheses to the && conditions make a difference in the ordering of the boolean evaluation? Is adding them even necessary?

Comment: @AlluringTopaz: No, parentheses are only useful if you want to break the precedence between `&&` and `||`. Take a look at the documentation for these operators in C#

Comment: The count is probably longer than the two below.

Comment: Nah, rolledback, I guess I broke something :-]

Comment: @paparazzo: Well, we don't know about `TimelineViewModel`, but take a look at the source code for `List<T>.Count` and `string.==`.

Comment: @HenrikHansen thanks for pointing this out. I actually should have given the implementation of TimelineViewModel (went over my head to do so). Because the == operator was not overridden in the concrete implementations of ViewModel...this actually caused an error during testing when the equality test failed. I should be using the Equals method I wrote instead. Should I include this in an answer, edit my original post or just leave it as a comment?

Comment: @AlluringTopaz: I think, the right way is to make a new answer, if you want to add to the original.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> public readonly string Title;
> ```

You shouldn't be using public fields. That's what we have properties for. You can make them `readonly` too by specifying just the `get` method like that:

```
public string Title { get; }
```

---

I find it's much easier and less error-prone to implement the equality via the `IEquatable<T>` interface. This gives you a strongly typed `Equals` method that you can use to redirect from the default one.

The signagure of you class would become

```
internal sealed class CanvasViewModel : ViewModel, IEquatable<CanvasViewModel>
```

and the respective implementations will be

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return obj is CanvasViewModel model && Equals(model);
}
```

You can save a few characters by using the *new* `is` operator that will try to cast the `obj` to the specified type and assign the result to the variable if it succeeds. Then it calls the second `Equals` method.

```
public bool Equals(CanvasViewModel other)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(other, null)) return false;
    if (ReferenceEquals(other, this)) return true;

    return
        other.Title == Title && 
        other.TimelineViewModel == TimelineViewModel &&
        other.ScaleViewModels.All(ScaleViewModels.Contains) &&
        other.ScaleViewModels.Count == ScaleViewModels.Count &&
        other.NoteMapViewModels.All(NoteMapViewModels.Contains) &&
        other.NoteMapViewModels.Count == NoteMapViewModels.Count);
    }
}
```

The first two conditions here are pretty generic and you use them for pretty every implementation of `Equals`. It doesn't make sense to try to chain them with the actual comparison. Leave them alone and focus on the other properties that are now also much easier to handle when you don't have to care about even more `()` or tricky `||` and `&&` combinations.

---

> ```
> internal abstract class ViewModel
> {
>     public override abstract bool Equals(object obj);
> }
> ```

We don't use `abstract class`es like this one because it has no default implementation for anything. It could, should be an interface. It's also not necessary to even define it because the `Equals` method can be overriden without it. It's already [`virtual`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx) because every object inherits it by default.

It would make much more sense if you defined it this way

```
internal interface IViewModel<T> : IEquatable<T>
{

}
```

and the respective class

```
internal sealed class CanvasViewModel : IViewModel<CanvasViewModel>
{
    ...
}
```

Some people argue that you shouldn't be using marker-interfaces, but I find they are very usefull and I do it all the time for various reasons.

Comment: I definitely will be updating the appropriate classes to match your advice.

Comment: @AlluringTopaz you can do both... I often do. I start with an interface and when I need a default implementation for something I just add an abstract class inbetween and inherit other classes from it. From the interface point of view nothing has changed and this still remains your contract.

Comment: Thanks :) I actually edited my comment thinking it would make sense to do exactly what you just said...then you posted lol. I will keep this in mind as well.

Answer (score 1):

As per Henrik Hansen's comment under the original post:

> @AlluringTopaz: I think, the right way is to make a new answer, if you want to add to the original.

and based on the recommendation to use a strongly typed `Equals` method in [t3chb0t's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/196573/171259), I should clarify that since no explicit `==` operator was provided for `TimelineViewModel` then, the  implementation of `IEquatable.Equals` in `CanvasViewModel` should be:

```
public bool Equals(CanvasViewModel other)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(other, null)) return false;
    if (ReferenceEquals(other, this)) return true;

    return
        other.Title == Title && 
        other.TimelineViewModel.Equals(TimelineViewModel) &&
        other.ScaleViewModels.All(ScaleViewModels.Contains) &&
        other.ScaleViewModels.Count == ScaleViewModels.Count &&
        other.NoteMapViewModels.All(NoteMapViewModels.Contains) &&
        other.NoteMapViewModels.Count == NoteMapViewModels.Count);
}
```